# Session expires when using ajax request in Laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have trouble when using an ajax request; the session expires, I don't understand why.

I get data with ajax to show info in "Real time", basically I'm showing a read field from a table. That's working fine, but sometimes the session expires and my web app redirects to the login page.

Here my code:

View

```
@foreach($data->getCollection()->all() as $value)
  <div id="read{{ $value->id }}"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function(){
    //-- Notification ID {{ $value->id }}
    var id = {{ $value->id }};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "{{ url('/') }}/admin/notifications/email/tracking/read",
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(data){ 
        //-- Read = 1
        if(data == 1) 
        { 
          data = 'Read'
        } else {
          data = 'Unread'
        }
        $("#read{{ $value->id }}").html(data);
        },
      });
  }, 3000); // send request each 60 seconds
  </script>
@endforeach
```

Controller

```
//-- Check if is read
public function read() {
  if(Request::ajax())
    {
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $data = NotificationsEmailTracking::find($id);
    return $data->read;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really related but you can just do `{{ url('admin/notifications/email/tracking/read')}}` instead of `{{ url('/') }}/admin/notifications/email/tracking/read`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem.

Comment: Have you noticed how long after the first request the session expires? 2 hours or sooner?

Comment: Minutes, even sometimes seconds. When I remove the jquery and ajax script, everything working fine.

Comment: I tried returning an integer, without retrieve the data from the data base and doesn't happened, it has not expired session expires, so the problem is laravel, any idea?

Comment: I don't understand... Anybody know something about this issue?